# Assign returned value to variable using pandoc-node in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, pandoc

I want to be able to assign a the returned result to a variable, but it wont work for me.  Any suggestions?

node.js api, using package [node-pandoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pandoc)

file returns as undefined

```
var nodePandoc = require('node-pandoc');
var src, args;
var file = ''; 

src = 'Lesson.doc';
args = '-f docx -t markdown';

callback = function (err, result) {
  if (err) return console.error('Oh No: ',err);
  console.log("callback result:",result);
  file = result
};

nodePandoc(src, args, callback);
console.log(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

so turns out it does work, but the the nodePandoc callback function runs after console.log(file), so that is why it is coming up as null